# Make page numbers distinct in index produced by bibleref package

Tags: formatting, indexing, verse

I'm using the the `bibleref` package, along with the `attrib`, `verse`, and `multind` packages, to cite verses from the bible and produce an index at the end of the document with the verse list and corresponding page numbers.  Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Quoting Bible passages
\usepackage{attrib}
\def\PreTrib{} \def\PostTrib{} % We'll do our own parens, thanks!
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{bibleref}
% Custom macros
\def\V#1 {\(^{#1}\)}
\def\vattrib#1#2{\attrib{(\ibibleverse{#1}#2)}}

% Indexing of Bible verse citations 
\usepackage{multind}
\makeindex{scripture}
\renewcommand{\biblerefindex}{\index{scripture}}
\biblerefstyle{default}
\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
\V{4} Thy father made our yoke grievous: now therefore ease thou somewhat the grievous servitude of thy father, and his heavy yoke that he put upon us, and we will serve thee. \vattrib{IIChronicles}{(10:4)}
\end{verse}

\clearpage

        \begin{verse}
        \V{1} In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth. \vattrib{Genesis}{(1:1)}
        \end{verse}

\clearpage

\printindex{scripture}{Index of Scripture References}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the index (shown below) produced by the above code puts the page numbers mighty close to the verse citations, and only separated by a comma, so that is almost looks like the page numbers are part of the citations.

[image]

How can I make the page numbers clearly distinct from the verse/chapter numbers?  For example, how can I align the page numbers on the right side of the document with leading ldots?  Or, how can I add the word "page" immediately to the left of the page numbers?  Or any other creative solution someone can think of...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a symbol in place of the ", " for the delimiter by using a style file input to `makeindex`.

For instance, with `style.ist` containing:

```
delim_0 " $\\bullet$ "
delim_1 " $\\bullet$ "
delim_2 " $\\bullet$ "
```

You would then run `makeindex -s style.ist texdocument`.  The changed `delim`s will alter the code that is placed between the item (of various levels in the index) and its first page number.  Note that the backslash needs to be escaped.  See some documentation [here](http://nwalsh.com/tex/texhelp/mkidx-24.html).

I think ideally, you might use a symbol that is sized somewhere between `\bullet` and `\cdot`, but I didn't find one quickly that would be suitable.  Or maybe `\cdot` would work fine for you.  Also, you might try `---` for a em-dash.

The result should appear as:

[image: index]

Comment: That's definitely helpful.  Do you know if it's possible to make this style definition in the source file instead of in a separate file?

Comment: Not very easily.  The change has to happen when the `.idx` file is translated by `makeindex` to the `.ind` file.  If you can use `imakeidx` package, you might be able to use the `options=-s style` option to `\makeindex` along with an appropriate `filecontents` environment, but it will still be using an external file (see [page 4 of imakeidx documentation](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/imakeidx/imakeidx.pdf)).

Comment: Instead of `$\\bullet$`, couldn't I do `Page:`?  (I'll try it myself later when I am able to.).

Comment: ", page " would work, too.